# SharePoint online - Email not sent from SPD workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to sent email from SPD workflow for SharePoint online environment. 
But the user configured in "To" field is unable to get the mails.

To address is picked from list item field, valid address is available.

Workflow gets completed successfully.

FYI, if i add any user to group and use "Send mail invitation" - those mail notification are received.

Is any additional configuration required from sending mail from SPD workflow of online environment or can some one tell the checkpoints for the same ?